# Stats from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
location start                          end
house    Mon Jul 25 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016 Mon Jul 25 19:04:33 GMT+01:00 2016
store    Mon Jul 26 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016 Mon Jul 26 19:04:33 GMT+01:00 2016
store    Mon Jul 27 19:04:30 GMT+01:00 2016 Mon Jul 27 19:04:33 GMT+01:00 2016
...      ...                            ...
```

with a few thousand more rows. It contains data about a users activity. It lists their location and the time they entered and left the location. They may visit the location multiple times. There is no comprehensive list of locations. I would like to produce a CSV file containing the total time spent in each location and the average time spent. For the sample data above, this would be my desired output:

```
 location, total time spent, average
 store, 6, 3
 house, 3, 3
```

I have written the following code to begin this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

filepath = '...'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
cat = set()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cat.add(df['StartLocation'][index].lower())
```

The above code creates a set, cat, which contains a list of unique locations. I now need to find all rows which contain that location. How can I do this efficiently?

EDIT: Using @DZY's advice I wrote this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime

def toEpoch(x):
    x1 = re.sub(r":(?=[^:]+$)", "", x)
    return (datetime.strptime(x1, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y').strftime('%s'))

filepath = '...'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
start = []
end = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['StartTime'][index] = toEpoch(df['StartTime'][index])
    df['EndTime'][index] = toEpoch(df['EndTime'][index])
    df['TimeTaken'][index] = int(df['EndTime'][index]) - int(df['StartTime'][index])
print(df.groupby('StartLocation').sum())
```

However, I am still confused by the last line. What is it actually summing?

Comment: You could start by explaining what is wrong with what you wrote.

Comment: (1) Subtract `end` from `start`, (2) `.groupby('location').sum()`, (3)  `.groupby('location').average()`

Comment: @DYZ Can you explain that a bit more please, you've lost me!

Comment: You may want to read more about aggregation with `.groupby()` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html